# Replacing std::map with std::set and search by index

Tags: c++, boost, vector, stl, set

Say we have a `map` with larger objects and an index value. The index value is also part of the larger object.

What I would like to know is whether it is possible to replace the `map` with a `set`, extracting the index value.

It is fairly easy to create a `set` that sorts on a functor comparing two larger objects by extracting the index value.

Which leaves searching by index value, which is not supported by default in a `set`, I think.

I was thinking of using `std::find_if`, but I believe that searches linearly, ignoring the fact we have  set.

Then I thought of using `std::binary_search` with a functor comparing the larger object and the value, but I believe that it doesn't work in this case as it wouldn't make use of the structure and would use traversal as it doesn't have a random access iterator. Is this correct? Or are there overloads which correctly handle this call on a `set`?

And then finally I was thinking of using a `boost::containter::flat_set`, as this has an underlying vector and thus presumably should be able to work well with `std::binary_search`?

But maybe there is an all together easier way to do this?

Before you answer just use a map where a map ought to be used - I am actually using a vector that is manually sorted (well `std::lower_bound`) and was thinking of replacing it with `boost::containter::flat_set`, but it doesn't seem to be easily possible to do so, so I might just stick with the vector.

Comment: Even after reading all your question, I fail to see why you just can't use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` ...

Comment: [Why You Shouldn't Use set, and What You Should Use Instead](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf)

Comment: @Cookie: It seems like that you completely misunderstood matts fud spreading rant.

Comment: `std::set` and `std::map` are just variations of each other: the linked pdf basically applies to both equally.  The core questions are "when do you insert?  How often do you insert as compared to lookup?  When you iterate over it, is order of elements important?  Do you need cheap copies of the container?  Is the index integral to the object's identity, or not?  Are there lots of elements?  Are you allergic to boost?  Do you have more than one index?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++14 will introduce the ability to lookup by a key that does not require the construction of the entire stored object. This can be used as follows:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct StringRef {
    StringRef(const std::string& s):x(&s[0]) { }
    StringRef(const char *s):x(s) { std::cout << "works: " << s << std::endl; }
    const char *x;    
};

struct Object {
    long long data;
    std::size_t index;
};
struct ObjectIndexer {
    ObjectIndexer(Object const& o) : index(o.index) {}
    ObjectIndexer(std::size_t index) : index(index) {}
    std::size_t index;
};
struct ObjComp {
    bool operator()(ObjectIndexer a, ObjectIndexer b) const { 
        return a.index < b.index; 
    }
    typedef void is_transparent; //Allows the comparison with non-Object types.
};

int main() {
    std::set<Object, ObjComp> stuff;
    stuff.insert(Object{135, 1});
    std::cout << stuff.find(ObjectIndexer(1))->data << "\n";
}
```

More generally, these sorts of problems where there are multiple ways of indexing your data can be solved using [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `boost::intrusive::set` which can utilize the object's index value directly. It has a `find(const KeyType & key, KeyValueCompare comp)` function with logarithmic complexity. There are also other set types based on splay trees, AVL trees, scapegoat trees etc. which may perform better depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to your contained object type:

- less than operator that only compares the object indices
- equality operator that only compares the object indices
- a constructor that takes your index type and initializes a dummy object with that value for the index

then you can pass your index type to find, lower_bound, equal_range, etc... and it will act the way you want. When you pass your index to the set's (or flat_set's) find methods it will construct a dummy object of the contained type to use for the comparisons.

Now if your object is *really* big, or expensive to construct, this might not be the way you want to go.